# Are there any interpreted languages in which you can dynamically modify the interpreter?

Tags: dynamic, language-agnostic, interpreter

I've been thinking about [this writing (apparently) by Mark Twain](http://www.i18nguy.com/twain.html) in which he starts off writing in English but throughout the text makes changes to the rules of spelling so that by the end he ends up with something probably best described as pseudo-German.

This made me wonder if there is interpreter for some established language in which one has access to the interpreter itself, so that you can change the syntax and structure of the language as you go along. For example, often an `if` clause is a keyword; is there a language that would let you change or redefine this on the fly? Imagine beginning a console session in one language, and by the end, working in another.

Clearly one could write an interpreter and run it, and perhaps there is no concrete distinction between doing this and modifying the interpreter. I'm not sure about this. Perhaps there are limits to the modifications you can make dynamically to any given interpreter?

These more open questions aside, I would simply like to know if there are any known interpreters that allow this at all? Or, perhaps, this ability is just a matter of extent and my question is badly posed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are certainly languages in which this kind of self-modifying behavior at the level of the language syntax itself is possible.  [Lisp programs can contain macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267862/what-makes-lisp-macros-so-special), which allow among other things the creation of new control constructs on the fly, to the extent that two Lisp programs that depend on extensive macro programming can look almost as if they are written in two different languages.  Forth is somewhat similar in that [a Forth interpreter provides a core set of just a dozen or so primitive operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29#Programmer.27s_perspective) on which a program must be built in the language of the problem domain (frequently some kind of real-world interaction that must be done precisely and programmatically, such as industrial robotics).  A Forth programmer creates an interpreter that understands a language specific to the problem he or she is trying to solve, then writes higher-level programs in that language.

In general the common idea here is that of languages or systems that treat [code and data as equivalent](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1803627) and give the user just as much power to modify one as the other.  Every Lisp program is a Lisp data structure, for example.  This is in contrast to a language such as Java, in which a sharp distinction is made between the program code and the data that it manipulates.

A related subject is that of [self-modifying low-level code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code), which was a fairly common technique among assembly-language programmers in the days of [minicomputers with complex instruction sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vax), and which spilled over somewhat into the early 8-bit and 16-bit microcomputer worlds.  In this programming idiom, for purposes of speed or memory savings, a program would be written with the "awareness" of the location where its compiled or interpreted instructions would be stored in memory, and could alter in place the actual machine-level instructions byte by byte to affect its behavior on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

Forth is the most obvious thing I can think of. It's concatenative and stack based, with the fundamental atom being a word. So you write a stream of words and they are performed in the order in which they're written with the stack being manipulated explicitly to effect parameter passing, results, etc. So a simple Forth program might look like:

```
6 3 + .
```

Which is the words `6`, `3`, `+` and `.`. The two numbers push their values onto the stack. The plus symbol pops the last two items from the stack, adds them and pushes the result. The full stop outputs whatever is at the top of the stack.

A fundamental part of Forth is that you define your own words. Since all words are first-class members of the runtime, in effect you build an application-specific grammar. Having defined the relevant words you might end up with code like:

```
red circle draw
```

That wold draw a red circle.

Forth interprets each sequence of words when it encounters them. However it distinguishes between compile-time and ordinary words. Compile-time words do things like have a sequence of words compiled and stored as a new word. So that's the equivalent of defining subroutines in a classic procedural language. They're also the means by which control structures are implemented. But you can also define your own compile-time words.

As a net result a Forth program usually defines its entire grammar, including relevant control words.

You can read a [basic introduction here](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/551.jvn.fall01/primer.htm#runtime).

Comment: [Factor](http://factorcode.org/) is another concatenative language with malleable syntax. Its semantics are more like Lisp than Forth, though.

Answer (score 2):

Prolog is an [homoiconic language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity), allowing meta interpreters (MIs) to be declined in a variety of ways. A meta interpreter - interpreting the interpreter - is a common and useful native construct in Prolog.

See [this page](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/acomip/acomip.html) for an introduction to this argument. An interesting and practical technique illustrated is *partial execution*:

> The overhead incurred by implementing these things using MIs can be compiled away using partial evaluation techniques.