# I get few warnings in my Lisp program but i do not know how to solve them

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

[image: Code and Warning]

This is my code and the warning. If anybody knows how I can get rid of the warnings, I will be thankful as my code is giving the right output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267862/what-makes-lisp-macros-so-special

Comment: Please post actual code, not an image of code.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what the argument list to **defmacro** does.  Doing `(defmacro lcomp (exp for var in list) ...)` means that you can call `(lcomp a b c d e)`.  I don't think that's what you're expecting, is it?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor right now the answer that I get is (4 64 36) which is needed but I am not sure what you exactly mean by(lcomp a b c d e)

Comment: I mean that all the things in the lama list of your macro are variables. However, I don't think you mean for "for" and "in" to be variables.  The defmacro lambda lay doesn't do pattern matching that way

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: It's not 'his' macro. The oldest version I found is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4621882/69545

Comment: well I just realised that that the warning is on Linux only, on Windows the code is fine :/

Comment: @Tim no, the code has the same issues in both places, even if one compiler doesn't complain as loudly.

Comment: @Joshua so how do you think I can solve it? or is there a way to solve it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on code that OP didn't write and hasn't attributed, and can't be useful to others (all code and warnings are images, so there is no searchability).

Comment: @TimJones Until the question has actual text (not an **image** of the code), people won't be able to search for it, so it's not useful to them.  The downvote button tooltip includes "it is unclear or not useful", so I think it applies.  As to "solving" this,  if you understand why `(defun foo (a b) (+ 1 a))` would generate a warning about b being unused, then you already understand why you get the warnings you do with this macro.  Your declaration says that the macro takes seven arguments, and you're only using five of them.

Comment: @TimJones On top of that, you're asking a question about code  that you didn't write.  That's fine, **if** you provide attribution for it.  Rainer Joswig found one of the places that code has appeared before, but you haven't said where you've found it, so you're essentially passing it off as your own (you even said "This is my code").

Answer (score 2):

Their are two ways:

1. you actually use the variables `FOR` and `IN`
2. you [declare to ignore](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_ignore.htm#ignore) the variables `FOR` and `IN`

Example:

```
CL-USER 30 > (defmacro foo (bar)
               `(list))
FOO

CL-USER 31 > (compile 'foo)
;;;*** Warning in FOO: BAR is bound but not referenced
FOO
((FOO #<CONDITIONS::SIMPLE-STYLE-WARNING 402000E4DB>))
NIL

CL-USER 32 > (defmacro foo (bar)
               (declare (ignore bar))
               `(list))
FOO

CL-USER 33 > (compile 'foo)
FOO
NIL
NIL
```

Comment: I understand that but what should I add to my code in order to get the warnings away?

Comment: @Tim Jones: Did you see the example?

Comment: Yes but I do not exactly understand it

Comment: well to be honest I would like to know something which will near my code not a new code

Comment: @TimJones The solution Rainer mentioned lets you  keep all your code.  All you'd have to add is `(declare (ignore for in))`, and everything else would be the same.  That's about as "near [your] code" as it can be.