# How does a C macro extend the syntax and semantics of the C programming language?

Tags: c

A book [1] that I am reading says this:

> One of the most interesting developments in programming languages has
> been the creation of extensible languages—languages whose syntax and
> semantics can be changed within a program. One of the earliest and
> most commonly proposed schemes for language extension is the macro
> definition.

How does a C macro extend the syntax and semantics of the C programming language?

For instance, this macro:

```
#define BUFSIZE 100
```

certainly doesn't seem to be extending the syntax and semantics of the C programming language.

Would you give an example (along with an explanation) of a macro that extends the syntax and semantics of the C programming language, please?

[1] *The Theory of Parsing, Translation, and Compiling, Volume 1 Parsing* by Aho and Ullman, page 58.

Comment: Does that book specifically mention C macros? Because macro systems in other languages (e.g.: Lisp) work quite differently

Comment: Ah! Thanks @UnholySheep in fact the book does not specifically mention C macros. Shall I assume, then, that C macros do not extend the syntax and semantics of the C programming language?

Comment: No. C macros are really just a preprocessing step before compilation.

Comment: See: [What makes Lisp macros so special?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/267862/2505965)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can consider this as 'extending' the syntax.
C macros can be used in 'hacky ways' to get some different syntax.

A simple example :

```c
#define startmain int main(){
#define endmain }
#define begin {
#define end }
```

This allows us to write programs like this (something similar to Verilog syntax)

```c
startmain
int i;
for(i=0; i<5; i++) begin
printf("%d\n",i);
end
endmain
```

But of course, some other languages like LISP have very advanced macro systems that let you do more.